# Excel VBA - Search for multiple Values in two Excel Sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, comparison

I have two Excel sheets and I need to copy values from one to the other.

Sheet 1: Contains ID´s in one column and Data in another, which I want to have in Sheet 2 later on.

Sheet 2: Contains the same ID´s and has to be extended with the corresponding Data values from Sheet 1.

How do I search for the matching ID´s and then copy the associated Data value from one excel sheet to the other?

Comment: This sounds like a simple job for [VLOOKUP()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=exact()` or

**Compare Two Sheets In The Same Workbook**:

1. Enable the workbook you want to compare two sheets within, and then
   click

> View > New Window

.
  2. Then go to the task bar to display the new window of the current
    workbook

3. Go to the two sheets you want to compare from each window and
   arrange them side by side
4. Now compare two sheets as you need.

**To Find out Difference**

1. Open the workbook which contains the sheets you want to compare and
   create a new sheet.
2. In the new sheet, select a blank cell, for instance, A1, and type
   this formula

> ```
> =IF(Sheet1!A1<> Sheet7!A1, "Sheet1:"&Sheet1!A1&" vs
>     Sheet7:"&Sheet7!A1, "")
> ```

, Sheet1 and Sheet7 are the sheets you want
    to compare with, and A1 is the first cell you want to compare.

3. Then drag the auto fill handle over the range you need to compare
   between two sheets.

**Compare Two Sheets In Two Different Workbooks**

If the two sheets you want to compare in two different workbooks, you can apply the View Side by Side utility to handle it.

1. Open the two sheets you want to compare between, and

> ```
> activate one
>     sheet and click View > View Side by Side.
> ```

2. Then the two sheets in two workbooks have been displayed
   horizontally.And then you can compare two sheets as you need.

Comment: Thank your so far. I want to compare values and to automatically copy a value. So only viewing doesnt help me.

Answer (score 0):

@Bandersnatch is the simplest solution

For this data on Sheet 1:

[image: Initial data]

.

The formula for Sheet2, Column B would be `=VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!A$1:B$6, 2)`

[image: VLookUp result]

---

In VBA:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindValsInWS1Vlookup()

    With Sheet2.Range("B2")

        .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], Sheet1!R1C[-1]:R6C, 2)"

        .AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B6")

    End With

End Sub
```

---

Another option (VBA only, with a dictionary object) - On Sheet 3:

---

```
Option Explicit

'Add ref in VBA window: Tools -> References... -> Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Public Sub FindValsInWS1Arrays()

    Dim arr1 As Variant, arr21 As Variant, arr22 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, d As Dictionary

    arr1 = Sheet1.UsedRange
    arr21 = Sheet3.UsedRange.Columns(1)
    arr22 = Sheet3.UsedRange.Columns(2)
    Set d = New Dictionary

    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        d(arr1(i, 1)) = arr1(i, 2)      'read the 2 columns from ws1 into a dictionary
    Next

    For i = LBound(arr21) To UBound(arr21)
        If d.Exists(arr21(i, 1)) Then arr22(i, 1) = d(arr21(i, 1))
    Next

    Sheet3.UsedRange.Columns(2) = arr22

End Sub
```

---

Result:

[image: VBA only]

Note: IDs cannot be duplicate for these solutions

Answer (score -1):

**I would like to suggest you two methods. First one is Non-VBA Solution and other is VBA.**

[image]

**Method 1:**

*Use this Array Formula in Cell A2 of Sheet 2.*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$E$6, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($G$1, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6), ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$E$6)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$E$6))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
```

**NB:** Drag this Formula Right to Column E then Down.
        Cell G1 in Sheet 2 has Match Code Q1.

**Method 2:**

```
Sub ExtractDuplicateID()


Dim sht As Worksheet 
Dim newsht As Worksheet 


Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set newsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")


Set dat = sht.Range("A1")
Set newdat = newsht.Range("A1")


Dim i, j
i = 1
j = 1


'Copy Header Values from Sheet1

newdat.Offset(0, 0).Value = dat.Offset(0, 0).Value 
newdat.Offset(0, 1).Value = dat.Offset(0, 2).Value 
newdat.Offset(0, 2).Value = dat.Offset(0, 3).Value 
newdat.Offset(0, 3).Value = dat.Offset(0, 4).Value 
newdat.Offset(0, 4).Value = dat.Offset(0, 5).Value 

Do While newdat.Offset(i, 0).Value <> "" Or newdat.Offset(i, 1).Value <> ""

  j = 1     

  Do While dat.Offset(j, 0).Value <> ""

    If (newdat.Offset(i, 0).Value = dat.Offset(j, 4).Value _
    Or newdat.Offset(i, 1).Value = dat.Offset(j, 5).Value) _
    And dat.Offset(j, 6).Value = "Q1" Then

      'Copy Header Values in Sheet2

      newdat.Offset(iRow, 0).Value = dat.Offset(j, 0).Value 
      newdat.Offset(iRow, 1).Value = dat.Offset(j, 2).Value 
      newdat.Offset(iRow, 2).Value = dat.Offset(j, 3).Value 
      newdat.Offset(iRow, 3).Value = dat.Offset(j, 4).Value 
      newdat.Offset(iRow, 4).Value = dat.Offset(j, 5).Value 

      iRow = iRow + 1
    End If
    j = j + 1     
  Loop

  i = i + 1     
Loop
End Sub
```

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: It would be my pleasure to learn the REASON, this answer is Down Voted !!